# SSL connection error: unknown error number

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Yesterday I was able to connect to my cloud SQL just fine. Today something changed, I keep getting an error saying failed to connect, SSL connection error: unknown error number.

I am trying to connect using MySQL workbench. I tried to create a new SQL instance as well, I get the same error. What has recently changed? IP's are fine and username and password are correct.

If I bring the instance down it takes a while to get an error message, however, once it is up it is giving me this error immediately. I know it is reaching the instance.

Any thoughts?

I am not trying to connect using SSL. "Unsecured connections are allowed to connect to this instance."

**Discovered the Problem**
It is a MySQL Workbench Issue. I can not seem to fix it. I have uninstalled and am pending on re-installing. Meanwhile using a different SQL manager and it is working just fine.

Comment: I have the same issue. My only difference is that the instance I'm connecting too has been off for a while. It was previously working...

Comment: It's a MySQL workbench issue. I tried a different manager and it works fine.

Comment: I haven't tried another manager, but I did create a brand new instance with the same problem. I must admit, I'm scared to stop or restart my production instance now!

Comment: I tried a different manager and was able to continue connecting to the database via other applications with no issues. The problem is MySQL Workbench. Not sure what changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled and Re-Installed MySQL Workbench fixed my problem. I am unsure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment about being too scared stop my instances, I had to update them for daylight savings time and then I couldn't connect to one!

More googling = more people with the same issue.

The answer is (for MySQL Workbench) is upgrade to 6.3.9 (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Info on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43207082/2066625